# How can I remove an element from a form using its ID in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, input

I am trying to add and delete an input from a form using javascript and jquery.

The idea is to have four buttons in the bottom. Two to add or delete extra inputs for percentages "A", and the other pair to add or delete extra inputs for percentages "B".

I was trying to do it the easy way by declaring four independent functions (i.e addA, removeA, addB, removeB), but I want to achieve this in a few lines. So I opted to declare it as a function with two input parameters. The code doesn't work anymore.

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="idesc">
  <input type='text' id='idesc_1' value='idesc_1'>
</div>

<div id="edesc">
  <input type='text' id='edesc_1' value='edesc_1'>
</div>

<input type="hidden" value="1" id="idinpt">
<input type="hidden" value="1" id="edinpt">

<button id="idadd">Add input for data A</button><button id="idrem">Remove input for data A</button>
<button id="edadd">Add input for data B</button><button id="edrem">Remove input for data B</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function add(inpnum, inpnam){
    var act_id = parseInt($('#'+inpnum).val());
  
  if(act_id<5){ //5 input
    var new_id = act_id+1;
    var new_input = "<input type='text' id='"+inpnam+"_"+new_id+"' value='"+inpnam+"_"+new_id+"'>";

    $('#'+inpnam).append(new_input);
    $('#'+inpnum).val(new_id);
    }
}

function remove(inpnum, inpnam){
    var last_id = $('#'+inpnum).val();

  if(last_id>1){
    $('#'+inpnam+'_'+last_id).remove();
    $('#'+inpnum).val(last_id-1);
  }
}

$('#edadd').on('click', add('edinpt','edesc'));
$('#edrem').on('click', remove('edinpt','edesc'));
$('#idadd').on('click', add('idinpt','idesc'));
$('#idrem').on('click', remove('idinpt','idesc'));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited you html, please see below, jquery codes must be inside the `$(function(){`
and your syntax in on click function is incorrect.

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="idesc">
  <input type='text' id='idesc_1' value='idesc_1'>
</div>

<div id="edesc">
  <input type='text' id='edesc_1' value='edesc_1'>
</div>

<input type="hidden" value="1" id="idinpt">
<input type="hidden" value="1" id="edinpt">

<button id="idadd">Add input for data A</button><button id="idrem">Remove input for data A</button>
<button id="edadd">Add input for data B</button><button id="edrem">Remove input for data B</button>


<script>
$(function(){

$('#edadd').on('click', function(){
     add('edinpt','edesc')
});

$('#edrem').on('click', function(){
     remove('edinpt','edesc')
});

$('#idadd').on('click', function(){
     add('idinpt','idesc')
});

$('#idrem').on('click', function(){
     remove('idinpt','idesc')
});

})

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function add(inpnum, inpnam){
    var act_id = parseInt($('#'+inpnum).val());
  
  if(act_id<5){ //5 input
    var new_id = act_id+1;
    var new_input = "<input type='text' id='"+inpnam+"_"+new_id+"' value='"+inpnam+"_"+new_id+"'>";

    $('#'+inpnam).append(new_input);
    $('#'+inpnum).val(new_id);
    }
}

function remove(inpnum, inpnam){
    var last_id = $('#'+inpnum).val();

  if(last_id>1){
    $('#'+inpnam+'_'+last_id).remove();
    $('#'+inpnum).val(last_id-1);
  }
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```